# A Connect Wall to be a proper knight

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be separated into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a word absent from the wall which can be placed in all four of those groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **GUN** | **JAY** | **KILL** | **LOCK** |
| **LODGE** | **MAZE** | **MIDNIGHT** | **MORE** |
| **PINT** | **PRION** | **RUNE** | **RUNNER** |
| **SHRIVEL** | **TIME** | **TOOL** | **WOLF** |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What new word can be placed in all four of those groups?**

Hint 1:

> One of the four groups needs a new head

Hint 2:

> One of the groups has a common suffix

Hint 3:

> One of the groups likes running in movie theaters

Comment: This is another tricky one...! I'm very confident I have the intended group (and its other members) for PRION, but the others are proving hard to pin down...

Comment: Hints every day! Even though you'll probably have broken this wall down soon enough :)

Comment: Not an answer but this comes to mind *rot13(xavtug)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe (despite a few red herrings in the list!) that the wall could be resolved as follows:

> Group 1: **A Periodic Table element anagrammed, plus a letter**
>  LODGE = (GOLD+E)*
>  PINT = (TIN+P)*
>  PRION = (IRON+P)*
>  SHRIVEL = (SILVER+H)*
>
>  Group 2: **Movies when suffixed with 'Runner'**
>  [*The MAZE Runner*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1790864/)
>  [*MIDNIGHT Runner*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6129904/)
>  [*RUNNER Runner*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2364841/)
>  [*TIME Runner*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108342/)
>
>  Group 3: **First letter can be changed to 'G'**
>  JAY → GAY
>  KILL → GILL
>  MORE → GORE
>  WOLF → GOLF
>
>  Group 4: **Another term when suffixed with 'SMITH'**
>  [GUNsmith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gunsmith), [LOCKsmith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/locksmith), [RUNEsmith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/runesmith), [TOOLsmith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toolsmith)
>
>  Note some of the red herrings here: There is a Kevin Costner film called *[The GUNrunner](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087374/)*, and MAZE can become GAZE when the initial letter is changed to a 'G'.

This means the missing word which could fit all 4 categories is:

> **BLADE**
>  (LEAD+B)*
>  [*BLADE Runner*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/)
>  BLADE → GLADE
>  [BLADEsmith](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bladesmith)
>
>  This also fits the title, since a good knight needs a decent blade (sword)!

Comment: You did get the correct answer (Congrats!), as for the grouping, here's something to help: Gur sbhegu tebhc'f fhssvk vf nobhg perngvat

Comment: @Auribouros Ah, then I know what it is! I originally considered that but didn't think RUNE fitted. Will amend...

Comment: @Auribouros I actually had this final answer too when I had only solved the one category, although another that might have fitted quite pleasingly was rot13(QENTBA, orvat (NETBA+Q)\*)!

Comment: A bit nitpicky for sure, but V hfrq *genafvgvba* zrgnyf nf nantenzf, your answer is great though!

Answer (score 1):

Tentative ...

**Group 1:**

> words that can have an S added to them (not at the end) to form a new word.

> PRION, MORE, KILL, TOOL (prison, morse, skill, stool).

**Group 2:**

> words that fit together with a mode of transport to form a new word.

> JAY, GUN, RUNNER, LOCK (jaywalking, railgun, roadrunner, airlock).

**Group 3:**

> words that go together with HALF.

> Half a PINT, half past MIDNIGHT, half TIME, half WOLF (werewolf?)

Remaining words, but I can't figure out the pattern for Group 4:

> LODGE, MAZE, RUNE, SHRIVEL

Comment: Fnqyl gung'f n pbzcyrgr ohfg, n tbbq rssbeg gubhtu!

Comment: Maybe it’s KILL, JAY, GUN, and LOCK? With kill being “roadkill”.